# Eliminating Multiple If Statements For Pulling A Specific Object Property

Tags: c#, object-property

Model:

```
public class ServiceHours
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public TimeSpan? Monday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Tuesday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Wednesday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Thursday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Friday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Saturday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Sunday { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently iterating through a list of "service hour" objects (they can hold an optional start time for 1 or multiple days of the week). I want to be able to dynamically grab the value that corresponds to the `DayOfWeek` enum from a `DateTime` object.

This works but isn't very elegant

```
var today = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;

foreach (var item in myItems)
{
    var time = new TimeSpan?();

    if (today == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        time = item.Monday;
    else if (today == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
        time = item.Tuesday;
    else if (today == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        time = item.Wednesday;
    else if (today == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        time = item.Thursday;
    else if (today == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        time = item.Friday;
    else if (today == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        time = item.Saturday;
    else if (today == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        time = item.Sunday;

    ...
}
```

UPDATE:
I ended up using reflection at the time, but this was a very poor, naive design to begin with and this question should've been posted to Code Review anyways - This question should be disregarded, just adding this notice in case any others come along. Thanks to those who attempted to help out regardless of the terrible question!

Comment: The code does not make a whole lot of sense.  You have a variable named `object`?  I _sincerely_ doubt that.  What is the intention of this code?  It feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: This sounds like a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and that would make it off-topic for this site

Comment: Alternatively you can use switch-case or create a Dictionary where keys are values of DayOfWeek and values are values of "object".

Comment: You _could_ put them in an array and then cast the `DayOfWeek` enum to an `int` to select from that array BUT it wouldn't be much better and it would require another allocation on the heap.

Comment: If you want to call your object 'object' it needs to be `@object` but don't ever do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this probably (did not compiled this code though)

```
object.GetType().GetProperty(today.DayOfWeek.ToSring()).GetValue(object)
```

use reflection to get property value,with only condition that `DayOfWeek` enum member has to have *exact* name of the property present in `object` type.

Comment: It seems like reflection is a bad idea here, we should figure out some more details from the OP

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to modify the class of the `object` that makes up your `objectList` variable, then try using a `Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan?>` in that class. `DayOfWeek` would be the `key` and `TimeSpan?` would be the `value`. This would simplify the class as well as eliminate the long `if-else` logic.

Also, if I'm not mistaken, this method would also be faster than using reflection and wouldn't rely on the property names of your `object` to be spelled exactly the same of the days of the week in `DayOfWeek` (if you needed to refactor for some reason in the future).

Here is an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<WeekObject> weekObjs = new List<WeekObject>();

    foreach (var obj in weekObjs)
    {
        SaveTime(obj.ID, obj.weekDictionary[DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek]);
    }
}

class WeekObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan?> weekDictionary { get; set; } = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan?>();

    public WeekObject ()
    {
        // Initialize dictionary here if you'd like
        weekDictionary.Add(DayOfWeek.Sunday, null);
    }
}

public static void SaveTime(int ID, TimeSpan? timeSpan)
{
    // Your code here
}
```